# Filtering a .find() based on another document returns [ ]

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my attempt at the query `AFTER` Sergiu Zaharie's answer was posted below:

```
    db.collection('users').find({_id:ObjectID('561f0cbd3ed5b852e95cab6a')}).limit(1).toArray(function(error, result) {
        if((!error) && (result[0] !== undefined) && result.length) {
            var user = result[0];

            console.log("User ID: ", user._id);
            console.log("Blocked users: ", user.blocked_users);
            console.log("passed quizzes: ", user.passed_quizzes);
            console.log("failed quizzes: ", user.failed_quizzes);

            db.collection('users').find({
                $and: [
                    { _id: { $in: [user._id] } },
                    { blocked_users: { $nin: [user.blocked_users] } },
                    { passed_quizzes: { $nin: [user.passed_quizzes] } },
                    { failed_quizzes: { $nin: [user.failed_quizzes] } }
                ]
            }).toArray(function(error, doc) {
                console.log("Results: ", doc);
            });
        }
    });
```

There's three users in the table, one with `ObjectID('561f0cbd3ed5b852e95cab6a')` (me), one with `ObjectID('561f0bbaff803840e917568d')` (michael) and one with `ObjectID('561f0b68d83c293fe960a25d')` (thomas).

The query above executed should have returned the account with the `ObjectID('561f0bbaff803840e917568d')` (Michael) instead query returned `[]` 0 results.

Data output:

```
User ID:  561f0cbd3ed5b852e95cab6a
Block users:  [ 561f0b68d83c293fe960a25d ]
passed quizzes:  []
failed quizzes:  []
Results:  []
```

That would make the query executed this:

```
db.collection.find({ 
    $and: [
        // Void out myself, because I'm looking for other people.
        { _id: { $nin: [ ObjectID('561f0cbd3ed5b852e95cab6a') ] } },
        // Void out blocked users, because I blocked them.
        { blocked_users: { $nin: [ObjectID('561f0b68d83c293fe960a25d')] } },
        // More array based filtering: (Blank arrays, shouldn't matter right now)

        { passed_quizzes: { $nin: [] } },
        { failed_quizzes: { $nin: [] } }
    ]
});
```

As stated, this leaves room for the document with `ObjectID('561f0bbaff803840e917568d')` to be returned by the find() statement. As it's not filtered per requirements above.

Comment: After @Sergiu's answer I have rewritten the question to a more programming oriented question.

Comment: You should not re-write your question-- but ask a new question instead -- now @Sergui answer makes no sense.....

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
db.collection.find(
    { [
        {_id: { $nin: [id] }},
        { "settings.min_rating": { $lt: rating }},
        { "settings.max_rating": { $gt: rating }}, 
        { blockedUsers: { $nin: [id] }}, 
        { discoveredUsers: { $nin: [id] }}  
      ] 
    }
)
```

Comment: The `$and` is assumed, you shouldn't even need that.

Comment: I added a TON of information to my question, trying to make my query work with your example, however having some issues with the query always returning `[]`

Comment: Fix your answer to have `{_id:{$nin:[id]}}` and I will accept it.

Comment: `{_id:{$nin:[id]}}` added